# Switch protcted mode (32bits) to real mode (16bits) in asm, low level

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-16, bios, low-level

I am creating an OS, and I need to call the BIOS in real mode, I tried this code but it has a bug:
[image]
The error on boch is

```
00002172825e[CPU0 ] check_cs: conforming code seg descriptor dpl > cpl
```

The code is :

```
    global go16
;______________________________________________________________________________________________________
;Switch to 16-bit real Mode
;IN/OUT:  nothing

go16:
    [BITS 32]

    cli                 ;Clear interrupts
    pop edx             ;save return location in edx
    jmp 0x20:PM16       ;Load CS with selector 0x20

;For go to 16-bit real mode, first we have to go to 16-bit protected mode
    [BITS 16]
PM16:
    mov ax, 0x28        ;0x28 is 16-bit protected mode selector.
    mov ss, ax  
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00+0x200    ;Stack hase base at 0x7c00+0x200    

    
    mov eax, cr0
    and eax, 0xfffffffe ;Clear protected enable bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax   
    jmp 0x50:realMode   ;Load CS and IP


realMode:
;Load segment registers with 16-bit Values.
    mov ax, 0x50
    mov ds, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ax, 0
    mov ss, ax
    mov ax, 0
    mov es, ax
    hlt
    mov sp, 0x7c00+0x200    

    cli
    lidt[.idtR]     ;Load real mode interrupt vector table
    sti

    push 0x50       ;New CS
    push dx         ;New IP (saved in edx)
    retf            ;Load CS, IP and Start real mode

;Real mode interrupt vector table
.idtR: 
    dw 0xffff       ;Limit
    dd 0            ;Base
```

The program stops at jmp 0x20:PM16
because he don't like 0x20
I need to call the bios to switch graphic mode because I can't do that in my bootloader
Thank you for your answer
PS :
My gdt is :

```
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, &kgdt[0]);
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0x9B, 0x0D, &kgdt[1]);      
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0x93, 0x0D, &kgdt[2]);    
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0x0, 0x97, 0x0D, &kgdt[3]);          

//user segment
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0xFF, 0x0D, &kgdt[4]); /* ucode */
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0xF3, 0x0D, &kgdt[5]); /* udata */
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0x0, 0xF7, 0x0D, &kgdt[6]); /* ustack */
```

Comment: Not a complete example. And "has a bug" is too unspecific: What happens and what did you expect instead?

Comment: `cli` then `hlt` may halt (freeze) the machine until an NMI occurs. And `mov cr0, eax` should be after `and eax`.

Comment: Is this meant to be a puzzle for us? This looks like you've thrown some pieces together and hope that something good will emerge from it.

Comment: I'm confused. Where's the mandatory long jump after clearing the low bit of CR0?

Comment: Are you aware what `mov [savcr0], eax` is doing after having set `ds` to `0x10`?

Comment: Why do you have a `hlt` before setting the `SP` register? Why don't you keep setting `SS` and `SP` together?

Comment: You need to include the GDT so people can see what's in those selectors 0x20 and 0x28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `jmp` or `call` to a different segment you need to obey one of the following priviledge rules:

- target DPL is equal to CPL
- target DPL is less or equal to CPL, but the target conforming bit is set

Looking at your selectors, the target DPL is 3 and the CPL is 0.

So to use `jmp 0x20:PM16`, change

```
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0xFF, 0x0D, &kgdt[4]); /* ucode */
```

into

```
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0x9F, 0x0D, &kgdt[4]); /* ucode */
```

---

> ```
> ;Real mode interrupt vector table
> .idtR: 
>     dw 0xffff       ;Limit
>     dd 0            ;Base
> ```

The correct limit would be 0x03FF (1023 in decimal)

[**edit**]

Since the goal is to go to real mode the *BIG* bit in the descriptors should be off to select 16-bit, and the *GRANULARITY* bit should be off to limit memory access to just 1MB.

```
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFF, 0x9E, 0x0, &kgdt[4]); /* ucode */
init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFF, 0x92, 0x0, &kgdt[5]); /* udata */
```

The order of things in your current program is different from what you can find [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode#Switching_from_Protected_Mode_to_Real_Mode) about switching from protected mode to real mode.

Comment: Thank you but now I have a new error `00002173089e[CPU0 ] fetch_raw_descriptor: GDT: index (50bf)a17 > limit (7f8)` the os can't launch go16 I don't know why

Comment: See the edit and find out what the new descriptors tell you.

Comment: "to limit memory access to just 1MB" -- In Real 86 Mode the limits should actually be set to 64 KiB, a single 16-bit segment each.

Comment: Thank you, now I can open PM16 function but when a do `jmp 0x50:realMode` I have a new error `math_abort: MSDOS compatibility FPU exception`

Comment: @KonectTeam It's impossible to even speculate about this latest error as we can not see what changes you have made (or not) to your code. I suggest you post a new question with all the relevant code, and certainly more than in the current question (that BTW was not very welcomed by some since it did not include enough for us to work with). Remember "better questions give better answers"